# QuarkusTest class cast exception BuildChainBuilder

Tags: java, gradle, junit, quarkus

I have a Gradle project with a Quarkus application to deploy a RESTful API.

The Gradle project is broken into 2 sub-projects: 'app' and 'spec'.  `spec` is using the Open API Generator to create the RestEasy Classic (RestEasy Reactive doesn't appear to be available at this taime) interfaces and classes.  `app` has a dependency on that sub-project.

The 'app' project has several directories/modules:

- app/src/main
- app/src/docker
- app/src/test
- app/src/componentTest
- app/src/smokeTest
- app/src/integrationTest

Unfortunately, only the unit tests (which are basic JUnit 5 tests) will run successfully (pass/fail).  I receive the following stack trace when attempting to execute the `@QuarkusTest` annotated tests:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder cannot be cast to class io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder (io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @45cff11c; io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder cannot be cast to class io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder (io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @45cff11c; io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.throwBootFailureException(QuarkusTestExtension.java:625)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.interceptTestClassConstructor(QuarkusTestExtension.java:696)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.InvocationInterceptor.interceptTestClassConstructor(InvocationInterceptor.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:93)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:92)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InterceptingExecutableInvoker.invoke(InterceptingExecutableInvoker.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestClassConstructor(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:310)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateTestClass(ClassTestDescriptor.java:79)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:286)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:277)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:68)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:147)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:127)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:90)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:55)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:102)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: class io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder cannot be cast to class io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder (io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder is in unnamed module of loader io.quarkus.bootstrap.classloading.QuarkusClassLoader @45cff11c; io.quarkus.builder.BuildChainBuilder is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension$TestBuildChainFunction$1.accept(QuarkusTestExtension.java:1257)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.QuarkusAugmentor.run(QuarkusAugmentor.java:130)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.runAugment(AugmentActionImpl.java:331)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:252)
    at io.quarkus.runner.bootstrap.AugmentActionImpl.createInitialRuntimeApplication(AugmentActionImpl.java:60)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.doJavaStart(QuarkusTestExtension.java:222)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.ensureStarted(QuarkusTestExtension.java:592)
    at io.quarkus.test.junit.QuarkusTestExtension.beforeAll(QuarkusTestExtension.java:640)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$12(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:395)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:211)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:84)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    ... 52 more
```

I thought the Gradle plugin Unbroken Dome TestSets might have been conflicting with the Quarkus platform generated modules `integrationTest` and `test`.  After replacing that plugin with basic configuration changes to achieve the same purpose, it still fails at the same point.

Moving the test to a Quarkus test module has no change either.

Not all modules will rely on the Quarkus Testing libraries as I'm aware of challenges mixing them.  For example, the smoke test will only rely on RestAssured to execute liveness/health checks after deploy.  Integration testing could be done with Docker instead of the Qaurkus library.

I would like to use component level testing on the CDI generated beans from Quarkus if I can, for example:

```
@RequestScoped
public class SomeService {
    @Inject
    DatabaseService databaseService;
}
```

In test:

```
@QuarkusTest
public class ComponentTest {
    @Inject 
    SomeService someService;

    @Test
    void test() {
         //Run tests on someService with injected dependencies
    }

}
```

So it all comes down to how to successfully get the component test to run.  Any help is appreciated.

- Gradle 7.5.1
- Java 17
- Quarkus 2.16.0.Final

Comment: Have had minor success. There was a recent change (Dec. '22, v2.16.0) in the Gradle plugin to support custom Test tasks. This get halfway there for component tests in a non-Quarkus dir such as `test` or `integrationTest`. The other half required setting dependencies for the `componentTest` configuration to use `testImplementation` instead of `componentTestImplementation`. This leaves dependencies for different test types all lumped together, e.g. JUnit tests don't need RestAssured.

Comment: For reference in Quarkus Gradle plugin: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/29808. Recently added behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the desired outcome of splitting Quarkus-specific tests from other types, the following Gradle changes will be required:

1. Define a new sourceSet.

```
sourceSets {
    smokeTest {
        compileClasspath += main.output
        runtimeClasspath += main.output
        java {
            srcDir file('src/smokeTest/java')
        }
        resources.srcDir file('src/smokeTest/resources')
    }
}
```

2. Create custom configuration that extends from test.

```
configurations {
    smokeTestImplementation.extendsFrom(testImplementation)
    smokeTestRuntimeOnly.extendsFrom(testRuntimeOnly)
}
```

3. Define a custom task of type Test.

```
task smokeTest(type: Test) {
    description = "Run smoke tests"
    group = "verification"
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.smokeTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.smokeTest.runtimeClasspath
}
```

4. Any dependencies required for the new sourceSet / Task should be included in `test` scope.

```
dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:${jupiterVersion}" 
// This is used for unit tests under 'test' directory.

    testImplementation "io.rest-assured:rest-assured:${restAssuredVersion}" 
// This is in same scope as unit tests but are smoke test dependencies
}
```

Write your new tests.

```
├── main
├── test
│   ├── java
│   └── resources
├── smokeTest
│   ├── java
│   └── resources
```

Any resources required by the new directory will also be in the `test`/resources directory.  This is likely a small issue with my configuration and could be corrected to pull from the appropriate directory, but it also helps when tests need to share the same resources, e.g. import.sql.

Addressing the original Class Cast Exception issue; I am guessing but think that the method Quarkus uses for swapping out core components for test vs dev vs prod is the source.  As I roughly understand it, Quarkus would use a different ClassLoader, for example, so when the Quarkus Test Extension tries to load BuildChainBuilder its using a production version and not the non-prod type.